# Odoo installation on XAMPP and rest api

Tags: php, rest, xampp, odoo

I am able to install the odoo on my system by downloading it from bitnami url and it was installed successfully at http://localhost:82 but I want to get installed on xampp.
I've a xampp installed on a windows machine and I want to install odoo on it so can anyone help me out on this, if its possible or not and if yes then how can i do that. I also want to use the rest api.

Please help me out on this one.

Thanks

Comment: for better understanding, could you please include your need or purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a cponflict as in WAR, I don't think so. :)

odoo is an ERP, with its own server (port 8069)

XAMPP is a combination of programs, which happen to be able to serve webpages. By default Apache (the A) is responding to port 80 and sometimes 443 (depending on configuration). It is possible to modify either odoo or Apache to respond to other ports, but if you stick to the default config, they should not be in each others way.

The one thing I think of which might give you some issues, is the dependencies of odoo and what XAMPP is installing. There might be some conflicts with these, also depending on the OS you are installing your programs.

Why not install both of them, and give us a small report what happened and what you think of it.....